# How to display 4column catalog category

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layout

In homepage "most viewed products", "new products", "featured products" are listing grid view products as 3column. Near that new products show the option  "VIEW ALL" to view all products. When i click that the page showing 3 column in products. I need 4 count, so i change as 4 count in catalog.xml.. But its not working. Please help.
  (I installed the TatavaSoft catalog extension)

Comment: so find which xml file he use to render catalog listing

Answer (score 1):

For all the product listing you have this available in the layout xml for each handle:

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

Identify the page layout of your page and change the appropriate value.
For example if your page uses the 3 columns layout change this:

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

into this

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>4</count></action>
```